# Bash Issue : sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sed

I'm trying pass a `curl` request and From response body , Im trying to grep for a key word "coin". If "`coin`" word matches , I need to get either "0" or "1" with the input URL as a `prefix` ( comma `delineated` ).

```
$for i in $(cat small);do curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" $i | grep "coin";echo $? | sed "s/^\(.\)/$i,\1/";done

#cat small

http://cuevana0.tv/
https://www.1111data.com/
```

I'm adding input as a prefix to the result "sed "s/^(.)/$i,\1/".

But i'm getting error as

```
$ for i in $(cat small);do curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" $i | grep "coin";echo $? | sed "s/^\(.\)/$i,\1/";done
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  633k    0  633k    0     0   909k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  908k
    <script src="https://coin-hive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script>
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this ? Though the above is not a good practice , But it will help me timely.

Expected Result :

```
http://cuevana0.tv/,0
```

Comment: You need a compound statement to run multiple commands i.e. `.. | { grep "coin";echo $?; } | ..` and even with it, it is highly bad sequence of coding practices. Give us a requirement on what you clearly want to do with a sample i/p and expected o/p

Comment: Thanks @Inian. I agree and I have updated the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a right way of coding this in `bash` avoiding useless `cat` usages and right usage of the tools (`grep`, return code) would be doing

```
#!/usr/local/env bash

while IFS= read -r url; do
    if curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "$url" 2>&1 | grep -q "coin"; then
        printf "%s,0\n" "$url" 
    else
        printf "%s,1\n" "$url" 
    fi
done < urlFile
```

The above code uses right way to

1. Loop through a file using input file re-direction and using a `while` loop and the `read` command (avoids breaking up lines when it has spaces)
2. Using return code of `grep` directly in `if` clause by suppressing the search output `-q` to console
3. Passing both `stdout` and `stderr` of `curl` to `grep` to look for the keyword.
4. Double-quoting the variables to not let them split due to Word splitting when spaces are present.

---

As the great [glenn-jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman]) points out, you could have the entire if-else clause replaced by this

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "$url" 2>&1 | grep -q "coin"; printf "%s,%d\n" "$url" $?
```

meaning to print the error code of `grep` right after the pipeline.

Comment: `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "$url" 2>&1 | grep -q "coin"; printf "%s,%d\n" "$url" $?` would be a little DRYer

Comment: @glennjackman I agree with the idea but I suspect `$?` might not be guaranteed to be `1` on a `curl` failure. We'd need to change `$?` to `$(( $? != 0 ))` or similar to be guaranteed to get a `0` or `1` value there.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem is that you're using the "/" character as a delimiter in the `sed` expression, but the string you're substituting also contains "/", so `sed` mistakes that for a delimiter and gets very confused. For example, on the URL "http://cuevana0.tv/", you're running the command:

```
sed "s/^\(.\)/http://cuevana0.tv/,\1/"
```

...which is invalid `sed` syntax because of the extra "/" characters. You could switch to using a different delimiter, like `... | sed "s@^\(.\)@$i,\1@"; ...` (provided you're sure "@" will never occur in one of your URLs).

But there's a much better way to do it. Rather than `echo`ing the status and then using an edit to add the URL, just use `echo "$i,$?"`.

Another thing here that's a bad idea: `for i in $(cat small)` is subject to a number of potential problems depending on what whitespace and/or wildcards the file might contain. In general, `while read -r i; do ... done <small` is much more predictable. Except that if anything inside the loop reads from stdin (or *might* read from stdin), you should use `while read -r i <&3; do ... done 3<small` instead.

Comment: Further explanation at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001